# What does DS18B20 stand for?

Tags: sensor, temperature, sourcing

We are looking to purchase DS18B20 temperature sensors from a supplier who claims to manufacture them themselves - but I cannot work out if DS18B20 is a product name for Dallas instruments (i.e. buying from other sources is not recommended) or whether DS18B20 refers method of measuring temperature.

Comment: It's an IC part number - belonging to Dallas as you say. But it's common (incorrect but common) for low cost PCB assemblies using that part to be sold under that part number. I'm guessing your "sensor" is an assembled PCB - made by your supplier. If they are reputable they will buy the IC itself (DS1820) from Dallas (OK, now Maxim) Otherwise ... who knows what you're getting?

Comment: I searched for "DS18B20" and got a maxim data sheet. https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS18B20.pdf So, if your supplier is maxim, you are ok.

Comment: I actually want to buy a waterproof probe with the chip inside. The supplier in question are these guys: https://jyntc.en.alibaba.com/?spm=a2700.8443308.0.0.sdQTuU

The problem I face is that I can't get a waterproof probe from anywhere other than the hobby market which is expensive or supplier in china which appear to be fake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DS18B20 is the part number for a component made only by Maxim, formerly Dallas Semiconductor.

The 'DS' prefix stands for 'Dallas Semiconductor'.

DS18B20 is not some sort of general noun for what this component is.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that answers my question. I can only find DS18B20 sold on places like Digikey but targeted to the hobby market, out of interest do you know where you can find temperature sensors that aren't £7 a go?

Comment: @PaulBarr Yes the DS18B20, they should be around 1.60 GBP. You can get 10 at amazon with free shipping https://www.amazon.co.uk/AZDelivery-DS18B20-Digital-Temperature-Sensor/dp/B01LXQF9B5/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1516285943&sr=8-5&keywords=DS18B20

Comment: Thanks Christian. The problem is that we need it to be waterproof, and from Dallas that suddenly makes the whole system £10: 

 https://www.amazon.co.uk/Dallas-Semiconductor-SEN-11050-Temperature-Waterproof/dp/B007XEY4OY/ref=sr_1_2?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1516286046&sr=1-2&keywords=waterproof+ds18b20

Comment: 10 water proof ones for 17 GBP
https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B075FV3PQR/ref=twister_B01M70GTLZ?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1
Do you need a proper supplier, or is a one off buy from amazon ok?

Comment: But then I assume those are fake ones from China again

Comment: the price is reasonable, they are sold by a german company. looks pretty good to me.
The part is coming from Asia anyway. It's not likemuch electronics are manufactured in the west.

Comment: @PaulBarr, as an example, www.digikey.co.uk have 18,000 in stock for £1.53 each (other suppliers are available). Plenty out there for you, surely...

Comment: Thanks Tony, it is specifically the waterproof probes with the DS18B20 inside the stainless probes we are looking for. And that is what I can't find. I can find plenty of DS18B20s by themselves, but as soon as they are in a probe they are either fake or much more expensive